# create new dataframe by matching a column in all the files in a folder

Tags: r, merge

There are n number of files in a folder.I want to create a dataframe by merging all the files in a folder with a common gene names.

```
 x1 <-
     gene            counts   normalized          value
    ZYG11B|79699     5691        39.158706        5.0332932
    ZYX|7791         22900       54.377240        71.2548929
    ZZEF1|23140      2244        34.791407        4.4889687
    ZZZ3|26009       5104        75.652432        9.7257335
```

expected output

```
 x_final <-
     gene     x1.value   x2.value   xn.vlaue
    ZYG11B    5.0332932  0.0000000  4.55969082
    ZYX       71.2548929 0.5106268  81.97369434
    ZZEF1     4.4889687  0.2499209  5.78737210
    ZZZ3      9.7257335  20.132950  0.16442613
```

Comment: Try reading the files in a list.  Then `Reduce(function(...) merge (..., by='gene'), lst)`

Comment: @ lst <- list.files(path = "./"); which returns list of all files in the folder,    Reduce(function(x) merge (x, by= "gene"),lst) returns error

Comment: You need to read the files, i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(lst, read.table, header=TRUE)`

Comment: lst <- list.files(path ="./");
lst1 <- lapply(lst, read.table, header=TRUE);
Reduce(function(x) merge(x, by='gene'), lst1);
Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])

Comment: Check the `str(lst1)`.Did you read the data correctly?

Comment: str(list1) 
List of 124
 $ :'data.frame': 20532 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ gene                    : Factor w/ 20532 levels "?|100130426",..: 1 
  ..$ counts              : int [1:20532] 0 102 
  ..$ normalized: num [1:20532] 0 4.21
  ..$ value                    : num [1:20532] 0 0.
 $ :'data.frame': 20532 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ gene                    : Factor w/ 20532 levels "?|100130426",..: 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92860/discussion-between-kryo-and-akrun).

Comment: My code was `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., ` If you are using anonymous fucntion, `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, ...`

Comment: Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='gene'), lst1)  gives a data.frame with 20532 obs. of  373 variables. But i am interested in getting only coumn "value" from files.

Comment: In that case, subset the dataset in the list` i.e. `lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) x[, c('gene', 'value')])`

Comment: @akrun..worked fine. What if i want to add the names of individual files in the folder as colnames in the final merged table.

Comment: I think if you set the names for the initial `lst1` i.e. `names(lst1) <- sub('\\..*', '', filenames)` and try with `Reduce` (not tested)